# Java-Stream - Mapping a Model to Entity - One-to-Many transformation

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to map a model `TradeValidationData` to an entity `TradeValidatioEntity` using `map()` operation is the stream.

*Here are the models:*

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class TradeValidationData {
    @JsonProperty("orderId")
    public Integer orderId;
    
    @JsonProperty("tradeValidations")
    public List<TradeValidation> tradeValidations;
}

@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class TradeValidation {
    @JsonProperty("clientReferenceId")
    public String clientReferenceId;
    
    @JsonProperty("tradeValidationMessages")
    public List<TradeValidationMessage> tradeValidationMessages;
}

@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class TradeValidationMessage {
    @JsonProperty("validationCode")
    public Integer validationCode;
    
    @JsonProperty("validationMessage")
    public String validationMessage;
}
```

*Here is the entity:*

```
public class TradeValidationEntity implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionId = 1L;
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private TradeValidationCompositeKey tradeValidationCompositeKey;
    
    @Column(name = "validation_message")
    private String validationMessage;
}

public class TradeValidationCompositeKey implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionId = 1L;
    
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private Integer orderId;
    
    @Column(name = "client_reference_id")
    private String clientReferenceId;
    
    @Column(name = "function_type_id")
    private Integer functionTypeId;
    
    @Column(name = "validation_id")
    private Integer validationId;
}
```

I have a model object `TradeValidationData` which in turn has a `List<TradeValidation>`. I need to transform each model `TradeValidation` into an entity `TradeValidationEntity`.

Each `TradeValidation` contains a list of *messages* `List<TradeValidationMessage>`.

In order to initialize `TradeValidationEntity` I need to create a *composite key* `TradeValidationCompositeKey`, which requires data from an instance of `TradeValidation` and a *message*.

Here's my previous code which makes use of the `Stream.forEach()` which is **working fine**. I hope it would help to convey my intention.

```
var tradeValidationEntities = new ArrayList<TradeValidationEntity>();

tradeValidationData.tradeValidations.stream().forEach(tradeValidation -> {
    tradeValidation.tradeValidationMessages.stream().forEach(tradeValidationMessage -> {
        var tradeValidationCompositeKey = new TradeValidationCompositeKey(orderId,
            tradeValidation.clientReferenceId, functionTypeId, tradeValidationMessage.getValidationCode());
            
        TradeValidationEntity tradeValidationEntity = new TradeValidationEntity();
        tradeValidationEntity.setTradeValidationCompositeKey(tradeValidationCompositeKey);
        tradeValidationEntity.setValidationMessage(tradeValidationMessage.validationMessage);
        
                tradeValidationEntities.add(tradeValidationEntity);
    });
});
```

And here's the current problematic attempt to map `TradeValidationData` to `TradeValidatioEntity`:

```
List<TradeValidationEntity> tradeValidationEntities = tradeValidationData.tradeValidations.stream()
    .map(tradeValidation -> {
        var tradeValidationEntity = new TradeValidationEntity();
        tradeValidation.tradeValidationMessages.stream()
            .map(tradeValidationMessage -> {
                var tradeValidationCompositeKey = new TradeValidationCompositeKey();
                tradeValidationCompositeKey.setOrderId(orderId);
                tradeValidationCompositeKey.setClientReferenceId(tradeValidation.clientReferenceId);
                tradeValidationCompositeKey.setFunctionTypeId(functionTypeId);
                tradeValidationCompositeKey.setValidationId(tradeValidationMessage.validationId);
                tradeValidationEntity.setTradeValidationCompositeKey(tradeValidationCompositeKey);
                tradeValidationEntity.setValidationMessage(tradeValidationMessage.getValidationMessage());
                return tradeValidationEntity;
            });
        return tradeValidationEntity;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I think the issue is with the second return statement I have for tradeValidationEntity. But I'm not sure what to return instead.

Comment: Don't think I understood your question - It would be to have a list of TradeValidationEntity that are mapped from the passed in TradeValidationData class (tradeValidationData is the variable)

Comment: I'm expecting the passed in orderId and functionTypeId being set to tradeValidationCompositeKey. The clientReferenceId from tradeValidation to set to the clientReferenceId of tradeValidationEntity. The validationCode and validationMessage from tradeValidationMessage to be set to the validationCode and validationMessage of tradeValidationEntity

Comment: To set the TradeValidationCompositeKey it will be a combination of tradeValidation and tradeValidationMessage. I think looking at the models should clarify your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248145/discussion-between-alexander-ivanchenko-and-rds80).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transform each `TradeValidation` object in the stream into **multiple** `TradeValidationEntity` instances.

`map()` operation is **not** the right tool for that purpose, it's meant for *one-to-one* transformation. Its *function* take one object and produces only one object.

To perform *one-to-many* transformation, you can use [`flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) operation. It expects a *function*, which take an element and produces a *stream of elements*.

That's how it might be implemented.

```
List<TradeValidationEntity> tradeValidationEntities = tradeValidationData.tradeValidations.stream()
    .flatMap(tradeValidation -> tradeValidation.tradeValidationMessages.stream()
        .map(tradeValidationMessage -> {
            var tradeValidationCompositeKey = new TradeValidationCompositeKey(orderId,
                tradeValidation.clientReferenceId, functionTypeId, tradeValidationMessage.getValidationCode());
    
            TradeValidationEntity tradeValidationEntity = new TradeValidationEntity();
            tradeValidationEntity.setTradeValidationCompositeKey(tradeValidationCompositeKey);
            tradeValidationEntity.setValidationMessage(tradeValidationMessage.validationMessage);
            
                    return tradeValidationEntity;
        })
    )
    .toList(); // for Java 16+ or collect(Collectors.toList())
```

***Note:***

- `map()` - is an *intermediate operation*, it doesn't produce a result, it spawns another stream.
- A stream which doesn't ends with a terminal operation will not be executed (unless it's consumed by another stream via some operations like `concat()`, or `flatMap()`).
- Multiline lambda expressions are difficult to read. Readability and conciseness is a main weapon of streams. I would advise considering extracting heavy logic from a function into a separate method with a self-explanatory name and replacing the multiline lambda with method reference.